# I am trying to add multiple users from a CSV in Linux using CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I need to create user accounts using the useradd command. I am struggling to figure out the best way to go about this.

I am thinking the best way would be to use a for loop as follows

```
cat file.csv | for i in {1..200}

do

useradd - *here is where I am lost...*

done
```

any advice or direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why only 1..200? Don't you want to process the entire file?

Comment: `while read -r field1 field2 field3 ... ; do ... done < file.csv` is the basic structure

Comment: Thanks I will be doing other tasks with the rest of the file. I am in the process of learning these basic commands. Hopefully I will be able to use your advice and take it from here thanks.